handle back button in nested navigators with pop scope flutter
I am trying to handle my nested navigators with Pop Scope.
Beacuse in the nested routes , when i tap the back button on the device the app closes.
The onInvoked method is deprecated so i couldn't solve this problem. Also couldn't figure out the implementation.
Here is my main_screen.dart file which handles the navigators:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/widgetlar/bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/providers/main_screen_provider.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/job_search.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/cuzdan.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/islerim.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/profil.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/kategori_sayfalari/komi_garson_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/kategori_sayfalari/etkinlik_gorevli_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/kategori_sayfalari/otel_gorevlisi_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/kategori_sayfalari/diger_isler_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/job_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/my_job_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/pending_applications_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/other_accepted_jobs_screen.dart';
import 'package:calistimapp/screens/update_worker_screen.dart';

class MainScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  const MainScreen({Key? key, required this.initialRoute}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends ConsumerState<MainScreen> {
  late final PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final initialPage = _getInitialPage(widget.initialRoute);
      ref.read(mainScreenProvider.notifier).setPage(initialPage);
      _pageController.jumpToPage(initialPage);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentIndex = ref.watch(mainScreenProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          ref.read(mainScreenProvider.notifier).setPage(index);
        },
        children: [
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => _generateRoute(settings, const JobSearchScreen()),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => _generateRoute(settings, const CuzdanScreen()),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => _generateRoute(settings, const IslerimScreen()),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => _generateRoute(settings, const ProfilScreen()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  int _getInitialPage(String route) {
    switch (route) {
      case '/job_search':
        return 0;
      case '/cuzdan':
        return 1;
      case '/islerim':
        return 2;
      case '/profil':
        return 3;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
  }

  PageRouteBuilder _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings, Widget defaultPage) {
    Widget page;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/komi_garson':
        page = const KomiGarsonScreen();
        break;
      case '/etkinlik_gorevli':
        page = const EtkinlikGorevliScreen();
        break;
      case '/otel_gorevlisi':
        page = const OtelGorevlisiScreen();
        break;
      case '/diger_isler':
        page = const DigerIslerScreen();
        break;
      case '/job_details':
        final jobId = settings.arguments as String;
        page = JobDetailsScreen(jobId: jobId);
      
      case '/my_job_details':
        final jobId = settings.arguments as String;
        page = MyJobDetailsScreen(jobId: jobId);
      
      case '/pending_applications':
        page = const PendingApplicationsScreen();
        break;
      case '/other_accepted_jobs':
        page = const OtherAcceptedJobsScreen();
        break;
      case '/update-worker':
        page = const UpdateWorkerScreen();
        break;
      
    
       
      default:
        page = defaultPage;
    }

    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
        const end = Offset.zero;
        const curve = Curves.easeInOut;
        var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
        var offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);
        return SlideTransition(
          position: offsetAnimation,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }
}

I tried to go back to the previous pages with the back button.
In the nested navigators/routes , the app closes instead of going back to the previous screen.

onPopInvoked is deprecated, instead use onPopInvokedWithResult. Present the PopScope code to get better help

The WillPopScope widget can be used with the approach from above in order to properly handle the back button in Flutter application in the case nested navigators are provided. It controls what should happen when you press the back button. As the onInvoked method is deprecated nowadays, the WillPopScope is the correct approach to reach this. So, you need to wrap these nested navigators with the WillPopScope and handle the back navigation behavior manually.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
